# Google Adwords: issue with tracking model and valueurl

Tags: google-ads

Sorry for screenshot, I'm italian and I have Gadwords in Italian.

I'm tryng to prepare a campaign.

I cannot absolutely insert the tracking model. I did insert the final url (first one) but every time I click on "test", I get the red alert.

Other this, I would add a parameter in the URL (e.g., see the {_a} with value "fr".

But when I click on the preview of ads (in my adwords console), Google Adwords link to my website without the params.

Where am I wrong? Thank you very much[image]